# How to count how many hours inside an hour range?

Tags: php, time

Can you help me with this?

I am creating an event planner and I have a function that consist of hour range. For example I have an event BIRTHDAY and this event is started from 13:15:00 hours to 18:30:00 hours. Now how can I count the hours inside this range?

I have a code like this:

```
<?php

$start = "13:15:00";
$end = "18:30:00";

$time = strtotime($start);
$timeStop = strtotime($end);

//how can I count the hours inside?

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `gmdate()` in this case:

```
$time = gmdate('H:i:s', $timeStop - $time); // feed seconds
echo $time;
```

Or with `DateTime` class also:

```
$time = new DateTime($start);
$timeStop = new DateTime($end);
$diff = $timeStop->diff($time);
echo $diff->format('%h:%i'); // hours minutes
```

Comment: Wow it works. Thanks for the fast reply. I really don't know this code.. :)

Comment: But what if I need to include the start and end of the time?

Comment: @itsmejodie yeah, the OP could elect to just use the `->h` property, i just formatted it, maybe the OP might use the minutes as well

Comment: @Jerielle the datetime class is built-in class in PHP, http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php. could you clarify? `include the start and end of the time`? isn't it `$start` and `$end`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$start = "13:15:00";
$end = "18:30:00";

$time = strtotime($start);
$timeStop = strtotime($end);

//To count hours in the range
$diff = intval(($timeStop - $time)/3600);
//3600 refers to 1 hour

?>
```

So you take the difference between two timestamps and divide by 3600 seconds to get the number of hours. `intval` is to get an integer value. You are free to use `round`, `ceil` or `floor`.