# Counting number of hours within time range

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function counting number of hours within different time ranges.

Let's say I have the time period 08:00 - 20:00, and the following time groups

```
08:00-10:00, 10:00-16:00, 16:00-20:00
```

I want the function to return an array with the number of hours in each group like this

```
08:00-10:00 => 2
10:00-16:00 => 6
16:00-20:00 => 4
```

If I give the function another time period e.g 09:00 - 12:00 it should return

```
08:00-10:00 => 1
10:00-16:00 => 2
16:00-20:00 => 0
```

EDIT

I have this code, but it's not counting properly ($group['count'] is always 0)

```
    $start = new DateTime( '09:00' );
    $end = new DateTime( '12:00' ); 

    $daterange = new DatePeriod($start, new DateInterval('PT1H') ,$end);

    $hourgroups = [
        ['start' => '08:00', 'end' => '11:00', 'count' => 0],
        ['start' => '11:00', 'end' => '15:00', 'count' => 0],
    ];

    foreach($daterange as $hour){
        foreach($hourgroups as $group){
            if($hour > new DateTime($group['start']) && $hour < new DateTime($group['end'])){
                $group['count'] ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far and where you got a specific error. Stack overflow is not a free programming service where you publish your requirements and get the code/program as a result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count how many hours inside an hour range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26092297/how-to-count-how-many-hours-inside-an-hour-range)

Comment: I would turn all time periods, like `08:00-10:00`, into two numbers, like `[8, 10]` and then match them against each other. That's how I would do this.

Comment: Is it always full hours?

Comment: Yes, input might be start 08:10 and end 11:15, but in that case I want it to count as 3 hours. Like working hours.

Comment: This looks like a perfect approach to train some Test Driven Development - why not start with simple cases, write test cases for them, implement the logic, then go to more complex parts

Comment: What exactly are your expectations for that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your inputs are, but I assumed they are string as in your question. If it's array then you can skip the explodes.  If it's something else then add a comment and I will change the code accordingly.

I make the string arrays and then create ranges of the times that I can intersect and count.

```
$groups = "08:00-10:00, 10:00-16:00, 16:00-20:00";
$input = "09:00 - 12:00";
$inputarr = explode(" - ", $input);
$inputhours = range((int)$inputarr[0], (int)$inputarr[1]-1); // [9,10,11]

$arr = explode("-", str_replace(", ", "-", $groups)); //["08:00", "10:00", "10:00", "16:00", "16:00", "20:00"]

foreach(array_chunk($arr, 2) as $item){
    $times[implode("-", $item)] = count(array_intersect($inputhours, range(substr($item[0],0,2), substr($item[1],0,2)-1)));
    // the range() creates arrays such as [8,9] , [10,11,12,13,14,15] , [16,17,18,19] 
    // these are intersected with the inputhours array created earlier and the count is
    // returned to an associative array with the timeranges as key 
}
```

https://3v4l.org/eUBbt

```
array(3) {
  ["08:00-10:00"]=>
  int(1)
  ["10:00-16:00"]=>
  int(2)
  ["16:00-20:00"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * @param   string start time
 * @param   string end time
 * @param   string start of period
 * @param   string end time
 * @return  int
 */

function hours($s, $e, $sp, $ep){
    // get max of starts of time dnd period
    $t1=max(new dateTime($s), new dateTime($sp));
    // get min of ends of time and period
    $t2=min(new DateTime($e), new dateTime($ep));
    // if $t2 <=  $t1  - no overlap
    return ($t2 > $t1) ? $t2->diff($t1)->h : 0;
}


echo 'Hours: ' . hours('08:00','10:00', '09:00', '16:00');
```

**UPDATE**

With your data structure

```
foreach($hourgroups as &$group){
        $group['count'] = hours($group['start'], $group['end'], $start, $end);             
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between ($hourgroups as &$group) and ($hourgroups as $group)? 

Thank you

Comment: In the second case group is reference to the source array so its modifications are saved in the source

Answer (score 0):

Create an Array with the Time stamps like this:

```
    $start = Array("08:00","10:00","16:00"); // Start Intervals
    $end = Array("10:00","16:00","20:00"); // Stop Intervals
```

Now you can easily run through them with an for loop like this:

```
                for ($i = 0; $i != sizeof($start); $i++) {
                    $time = new DateTime($start[$i]);
                    $timeStop = new DateTime($end[$i]);
                    $diff = $timeStop->diff($time); // Get the Difference between end and start
                    echo('
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                '.$start[$i].'
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                '.$end[$i].'
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                '.$diff->format('%h:%i').'
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ');
                }
```

Resault:

```
Start|End  |Duration
08:00|10:00|2:0
10:00|16:00|6:0
16:00|20:00|4:0
```

--- EDIT ---

Here is the Code and Result with your Data Structure ;)

Code:

```
<?php
    $stard = '09:00';
    $end = '12:00';
    $stard = new DateTime($stard);
    $end = new DateTime($end);

    $daterange = new DatePeriod($stard, new DateInterval('PT1H') ,$end);

    $stard = $stard->format('H');
    $end = $end->format('H');

    $hourgroups = [
        ['start' => '08:00', 'end' => '11:00', 'duration' => 0],
        ['start' => '11:00', 'end' => '15:00', 'duration' => 0],
    ];
    echo("Duration:<br>");
    for($i = 0; $i != sizeof($hourgroups); $i++) {
        $time = new DateTime($hourgroups[$i]['start']);
        $timeStop = new DateTime($hourgroups[$i]['end']);
        $beging = $time->format('H');
        $ending = $timeStop->format('H');

            foreach($daterange as $hour){
                $checker = $hour->format('H');
                if($checker > $beging && $checker < $ending){
                    $hourgroups[$i]['duration'] = $hourgroups[$i]['duration'] + 1;
                }
            }

        echo(($hourgroups[$i]['duration'] + 1)."<br>");
    }
?>
```

The resault of this code is:

```
Duration:
3
1
```

Comment: This is not what is asked

Comment: Sorry for the late Edit I was a bit busy xD

Comment: You still don't get the correct output. Also your $stard and $end are completly unsued in the code.

Comment: Oh my.... `$stard = substr((string)$stard->format('H'),0,2);` is the exact same as `$stard = $stard->format('H');` which also is the same as `$stard = substr($stard,0,2);` but without all the DateTime.

Comment: You messed up the code. I said **without** DateTime. Off course it will hinder the performance. You make a DateTime that returns the same thing, then you string cast a string, and then you substring the first two characters of a string that is two characters. https://3v4l.org/uruYL . ***to be sure that it will be a number between 01 and 99*** what clock goes to 99?

Comment: Just in case the industry protocol goes up to 100, that's another point. So that you give peace I have the code adapted also whom the result remains the same.